# Why double click appearing?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When i clicking on menu item i get 2 click events instead of one - where is the problem?

HTML:

```
<nav class="nav-collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="dropdown active">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu 1 <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#1">Item</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#2">Item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu 2 <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#3">Item</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#4">Item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

JS

```
jQuery('nav li').on('click', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]',  function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nonamez/ekMSy/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think people are thinking too hard about this. Just remove the `li` part of the selector:

```
jQuery('nav').on('click', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]',  function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(this);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W62Sw/1/

The reason you had the problem before is because the target elements (`a[data-toggle="tab"]`) are found twice from this parent selector: `'nav li'` (since you have nested menus).

Of course, another option is to change the main selector to `jQuery('nav > li')` so it only selects the immediate children `<li>` elements, but I really don't see a use for that. Your main point is just to target all the `a[data-toggle="tab"]`, so just keep the container as `nav`. Sure, it makes for a bigger parent for the event delegation, but technically it'll only bind one event (instead of one to each `<li>`) and it allows for `a[data-toggle="tab"]` to be anywhere in the `ul.nav` element.

Answer (score 1):

Because the event is being propagated to the parent `li`.

You need to prevent that action using `stopPropagation`:

```
jQuery('nav li').on('click', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]',  function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert(this);
});
```

Here's an updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ekMSy/3/).

Comment: Can anyone explain the DV here, please?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have li inside li, try this instead:

```
jQuery("nav li:has('a[data-toggle]')").on('click', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]',  function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```

Another solution, more cleaner in my opinion is to use the parent `<ul>` as the element to attach your event delegation handler, like this:

```
jQuery("ul.nav").on('click', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]',  function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```

Comment: Or just get rid of the `li` completely, unless OP has `a` elements inside of the `nav` that aren't part of a `ul`.